# How to modify the signature of a a function without breaking it in a library

Tags: python, shared-libraries, libraries

I am building a library that other people in my company are consuming.
An example of a function in this library is:

```
def foo(bar, *baz)
```

Now, we came up with a new named optional boolean parameter `qux` that we want to add to `foo`.
I tried to add it at the end:

```
def foo(bar, *baz, qux=False)
```

But this will not work as it's an invalid syntax (my IDE even highlights this: *regular parameter after * parameter*).
Adding it before `*baz` works fine:

```
def foo(bar, qux=False, *baz)
```

But this is not backwards compatible, and it will break all the code for every dev that updates this library.

How can I add this new parameter to my function, without breaking all my coworkers apps?

Will all of them need to modify their code to accept this new function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*baz` is a catch-all argument and you can't add a new named argument after that. As a workaround you could do the following:

```
def foo(bar, *baz, **kwargs):
    qux = kwargs.get("qux", False)
    # ... rest of your implementation
```

Granted this won't help your IDE catch errors calling this function, but you won't have to modify it everywhere.